# How check TLSv1.2 is enabled or not in wildfly 10.1

Tags: java, server, wildfly, tls1.2

Acording title i want to know how to check TLSv1.2 is enabled or not in server.

Server :

> CentOS 7 ||
>   wildfly 10.1 ||
>   jdk 1.8.0_161

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware if there is a wildfly specific way, but you can always use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), for monitoring traffic to the server.

Install it, apply a filter, where destination address is the server's address.

You will see something similar to this:

[image]

In my case, server supports `TLSv1.2`.

Comment: Thank you @leopal . I follow from your instruction . I found TLSv1.2 like your snapshot. That mean my server supports TLSv.1.2 right?

Comment: @DKKs Exactly! Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can specify -Djavax.net.debug=all which will log TLS handshake, from which it can be also clear TLSv1.2 is used.

Also note you can ensure TLSv1.2 is used by configuring WildFly with https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/10.1/subsystem/undertow/server/https-listener/index.html#attr-enabled-protocols